# Material UI Date Picker reads Event.target.value as undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to have the user specified minutes and seconds added onto the date picker component. For instance a user would be able to type out 2:30 within the input box without any issues.

The issue I am having is that it says `event.target.value` is undefined when clearly there is a value there. I assume it has to do with my function that is converting seconds into minutes.

```js
  function handleMinuteSelectionChange(event) {
    const minuteSelection = event.target.value;

    if (isNaN(minuteSelection)) {
      window.alert("Please select a number");
    } else {
      const minuteSelectionS = parseInt(minuteSelection);
      if (minuteSelectionS > 59 || minuteSelectionS < 0) {
        window.alert("Please choose a minutes value between 0 and 59");
      } else {
        console.log(`Minute selection changed: ${minuteSelectionS}`);
        setTempTargetTimeS(minuteSelectionS * 60);
      }
    }
  }
```

My component

```js
          <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
            <TimePicker
              ampmInClock
              views={["minutes", "seconds"]}
              inputFormat="mm:ss"
              mask="__:__"
              label="Minutes and seconds"
              value={tempTargetTimeS / 60}
              onChange={handleMinuteSelectionChange}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  className={recorderClasses.targetTimeSelection}
                />
              )}
            />
          </LocalizationProvider>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to MUI's documentation, the new value is not passed inside an event object, but you just get the value. So you can get it like so:

```
  function handleMinuteSelectionChange(value) {
    const minuteSelection = value;

    if (isNaN(minuteSelection)) {
      window.alert("Please select a number");
    } else {
      const minuteSelectionS = parseInt(minuteSelection);
      if (minuteSelectionS > 59 || minuteSelectionS < 0) {
        window.alert("Please choose a minutes value between 0 and 59");
      } else {
        console.log(`Minute selection changed: ${minuteSelectionS}`);
        setTempTargetTimeS(minuteSelectionS * 60);
      }
    }
  }
```

[MUI Time Picker Documentation](https://mui.com/components/time-picker/)